# IIS aways returns an empty page

Tags: c#, iis

I am deploying a site built as a set of projects in a solution which is deployed as a series of websites (one project = one url).

The coding lanague is c# and the site uses a mssql db accessed via linq.

Everything works ok on the development server but at the moment, all pages with dynamically created elements (i.e all `<asp>` and custom tags) output a blank page with the following source code. Static pages (standard html and aspx) display correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

I normally work with php on LAMP and this behaviour is unlike anything I've seen in that setup. I need some fresh ideas on causes / resolution of this error (preferably step by step / tutorial links - like I say IIS/c#.net is not my normal enviroment).

Things I have tried with no effect whatsoever:

- altering permissions on site folders
- altering web.config settings
- Redeploying site files via copy / paste and the vb publish option with various settings
- Plus a whole ton (over two days so far) of internet research

Thanks for all replies.

edit:
version numbers:

iis: v6.1 (bulid: 7601)
OS: Windows web server 2008 R2 / Service pack 1
.net: v4

second edit:

Sample page:

aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dbtest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Rica.Yoodul.dbtest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>test</h1>

        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Rica.Yoodul
{
    public partial class dbtest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RicaConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            myConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.MaritialStatus", myConnection);

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                Literal1.Text = Literal1.Text + myReader["Name"].ToString();
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

edit:

Something I didn't add: Based on some of the other behaviour the server is displaying, I think the most likely culprit is misconfiguration of the server.

edit:

OK I've narrowed down the cause a little. By taking out everything except the langauge attribute in the first line of the front end file I can get the server to display the static content.#

edit:

OK http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference covers the use of the iis config files. Only I went to the path indicated on the page and I don't appear to have any config files at all. How do I comfirm / fix this?

Comment: please provide us the OS version, IIS version, .NET version

Comment: You say ASPX pages display correctly but pages with "dynamically created elements" do not - can you explain what you mean by the latter?

Comment: have you set the default page for your site

Comment: @DanPuzey ASPX pages that lack any .net controls display correctly. Any others (even a single literal) blank screen. I have tested this with an extremely simple dump a query result into a literal page and it holds true.

Comment: Have you registered ASP with IIS?   Open a command prompt and run `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` (your path may vary slightly).

Comment: @hatsoft: yes. extra characters.

Comment: @DanPuzey Please claify what you mean by run exit. ok irrelevent now

Comment: @DanPuzey Did as you suggested, but did not have success.

Comment: Can you post the source code for a simple page that does not work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your production server doesn't have ASP.NET correctly installed/registered, so your pages are being treated as simple text documents rather than code. This can sometimes happen if you install .NET before installing IIS, for example.

To confirm this, put together a barebones page that includes a mix of HTML and ASP.NET...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ASP.NET Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello from HTML</p>
        <p><%= "Hello from ASP.NET" %></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you load that up and only get the plain-HTML greeting, use your browser's "View Source" option and see what you're actually getting. If your ASP.NET source-code is shown in the source the browser's receiving, that confirms that IIS didn't treat it as an ASP.NET file - which means ASP.NET isn't installed correctly or is disabled.

Comment: OK I got both strings display correctly. Which is the firtst thing to process correctly since I started.

Comment: Double-check that you don't have either of the <%= and %> strings in the browser's "View Source" window as well, and that neither string is in quotes

Comment: the source is <p>Hello from HTML</p><p>Hello from ASP.NET</p>